# How meta is today's metamathematics?

Tags: soft-question, meta-math

I've recently been interested in the study of metamathematics, as mathematical theories about mathematical theories has quite the charm of novelty to it from the perspective of an undergrad. I recall in an interview with Steven Wolfram that some regard prominent figures (like Bertrand Russel) to have done extremely esoteric research in even higher 'orders' of metamathematics. I.e; meta-mathematics and etc.

> Although there may not be a method to measure such, what is the highest order of metamathematics that is has been reached, or is being researched in academia?

Any insight or references to papers would be appreciated.

Comment: You said it yourself: There is not a method to measure how "meta" something is

Comment: @MorganRodgers I agree, but surely there is at least just as much of a difference between higher orders of meta mathematics as there is between mathematics and metamathematics.

Comment: I don't know what that means. How can we say that if we can't quantify how much of a difference there is? Is there an actual question you have related to this? Maybe there is a way to word it in a way that can be answered.

Comment: @MorganRodgers As an example to what I mean, consider the one from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics): ' "2+2=4" [belongs] to mathematics while categorizing the proposition "'2+2=4' is valid" [belongs] to metamathematics." '. Surely there are theorems of higher orders that talk about the validity of the validity of propositions like "2+2=4", etc. Ironically, clearly we would need an order of metamathematics higher than all other orders to quantify a difference. My question pertains to what research is done that go to such extreme high-order.

Comment: There certainly is active research in the field of metamathematics. It doesn't really get separated in terms of what "level of meta" it is.